# JAVA OpenGL - Scale image to fit window

Tags: java, opengl, resize, image-resizing, wavefront

I am having trouble with a program i am writing. Currently i am reading a OBJ file and rendering it correctly. But my problem is, some images don't fit my window.

I've tried to scale it using glScalef, but the image is still deformed. (almost always on Z)

and here is how i set my window:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION); 
    gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
    float w = gLDrawable.getWidth(); 
    float h = gLDrawable.getHeight(); 

    if(w > h) gl.glOrtho(-1.0*(w/h), 1.0*w/h, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
    else gl.glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0*(h/w), 1.0*h/w, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Here is my Scale attempt

```
        if(m.getXVertexMax() - m.getXVertexMin() >  w) gl.glScalef(w/(m.getXVertexMax() - m.getXVertexMin()), 1, 1);
    else gl.glScalef(1/(m.getXVertexMax() - m.getXVertexMin()), 1, 1);

    if(m.getYVertexMax() - m.getYVertexMin() > h) gl.glScalef(1, h/(m.getYVertexMax() - m.getYVertexMin()), 1);
    else gl.glScalef(1, 1/(m.getYVertexMax() - m.getYVertexMin()), 1);

    gl.glScalef(1, 1, (1/(m.getZVertexMax() - m.getZVertexMin())));
```

[image]

[image]

No mater what i try, the image is always either short on the x or very large on the z!

Can someone please give a hand here? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scale uniformly, if you scale the X axis, scale the Y and Z by the same amount.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really, i am new to OpenGL so this was probably a very noob question but you answer made me realize what was suppose to be "the basic".... Thank you again! :-)